# MongoDb query needs to be framed

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection named 'Dealer' with following fields.

1) userId
2) dealerId
3) code
4) origin (having values 'UUM', 'MMT', 'TTC')

In the above collection, I need to get unique dealer records with unique combination of (userId + dealerId). If two records are having same 'userId' and 'dealerId' then I need to check the origin field and the record with value not equal to 'UUM' needs to be returned in resultset.

This is what I reached up to, as of now:

```
db.dealer.aggregate(
     [ 
        { 
           $sort: { origin: 1 } 
        }, 
        {
           $group: 
           { 
              _id: { 
                      dealerId:"$dealerId",
                      recordId:"$recordId"
                    }, 
              origin: { 
                      $first: "$origin" 
                    }
            } 
         } 
      ])
```

How can I make an aggregation query for the above scenario.Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you at least show what you have attempted?

Comment: This is what I reach upto as of now:

db.dealer.aggregate([ { $sort: { origin: 1 } },
    {$group: { _id: { dealerId:"$dealerId",recordId:"$recordId"}, origin: { $first: "$origin" }} }
])

Comment: Where does the `record` field come from?

Comment: Can there be more than one record with `record` value `"UUM"` for a given pair `(userId, dealerId)`? If so, do you want to return all of them or just one (or, I suppose, something in between)? If just one,  how would you pick which one?

Answer (score 1):

To reduce memory usage, I would filter the docs that have don't have a UUM origin.
Then the group by dealers and users.

I'm not sure why you're sorting and grouping by dealer + record.

### Setup

```
> db.dealerTest.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "userId" : "u1", "dealerId" : "d1", "code" : 1, "origin" : "UUM" }
{ "_id" : 2, "userId" : "u1", "dealerId" : "d1", "code" : 2, "origin" : "UUM" }
{ "_id" : 3, "userId" : "u1", "dealerId" : "d1", "code" : 3, "origin" : "TTC" }
{ "_id" : 4, "userId" : "u2", "dealerId" : "d1", "code" : 4, "origin" : "TTC" }
{ "_id" : 5, "userId" : "u2", "dealerId" : "d1", "code" : 5, "origin" : "MMT" }
{ "_id" : 6, "userId" : "u2", "dealerId" : "d2", "code" : 6, "origin" : "UUM" }
```

Code:

```
db.dealerTest.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        origin: {
            $ne: "UUM"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            dealerId: "$dealerId",
            userId: "$userId"
        },
        docIds: { $addToSet : "$_id" },
        origins: { $addToSet : "$origin" }
    }
}]);
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : { "dealerId" : "d1", "userId" : "u2" }, "docIds" : [ 5, 4 ], "origins" : [ "MMT", "TTC" ] }
{ "_id" : { "dealerId" : "d1", "userId" : "u1" }, "docIds" : [ 3 ], "origins" : [ "TTC" ] }
```